# findOne() method is undefined

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I am new to SpringBoot , and learning about JPA.
I am trying to create a method to retreive the instance(row) of my Table(entity)
based on a variable Id(String, primary key) .

I have created an interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository
here Topic is my entity class and String is primary key data type(id).

Now while I am following some tutorial , I am trying to retrieve the row based on Id , using the method findOne(id) 
eg. topicRepository.findOne(id);

but the method is not located or undefined to use.
Please help me out with this. I am a newbie.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tutorial you are following is using an older version of Spring Data than you have used in your project. In Spring Data 2.0+, there are several methods that have been replaced with similar methods.

Instead of `findOne(id)` you can use `findById(id)` from the [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)